# Using s3 policy variables in an "Application Users" context

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am aware of policy variables in s3 and their usage. However, to my understanding, it seems this is applicable at an "IAM USER" level...

In my app, I have staff (Admin staff, regular staff) at HQ, Region, district levels.
Please see the attached picture.

[image]

Since these are application users, I have to enforce the s3 folder access via roles. Please let me know how to implement this.

I thought of creating the following roles
HQ Admin staff role, HQ regular staff role, Regional AdminStaff role, Regional Regular staff role,
District Admin staff role, District regular staff role
and assign these roles to the user depending on where they fit.

but at run time from within the app, how can these roles be applied?

The document access hierarchy is enforced top-down.
HQ--> Regional--->District

The HQ Admin staff are not allowed to see each other docs but can see everything below their level.
The HQ regular staff cannot see HQ Admin staff folders, and cannot see other HQ regular staff folders but can see everything else below.

and so it goes.... for Regional Admin staff and Regional regular staff, and district admin staff and district regular staff, etc.